# Rails 4 Fonts not rendering after precompile in production on Apache

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, apache, fonts

I have a font in `app/assets/fonts/myfont.TTF`. This is working fine in development, but when I deploy on Apache using phusion passenger, and after precompiling assets, it is not being loaded.

Following is the relevant CSS

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: 'myfont';
  src: url('/assets/myfont.TTF');
}
```

Comment: You need to replace "url('/assets/myfont.TTF')" with "asset-url('myfont.TTF')" to tell rails to compile your font.

Answer (score 1):

As Kengo States you need to change

```
url('/assets/myfont.TTF')
```

to

```
asset-url('myfont.TTF')
```

you just have an error in your path syntax that is all